# Get checked state of dynamically added check boxes

Tags: c#, winforms

i added check boxes dynamically in a panel and after executing how can i get which check boxes are selected when a button is clicked.

```
public int x=550 ,y=10;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var panel1 = new Panel()
        {
            Size = new Size(600, 70),
            Location = new Point(20, 130),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chkpremiumtickets = new CheckBox();
            chkpremiumtickets.Text = " ";
            chkpremiumtickets.Name = "chkboxpremiumtickets";
            chkpremiumtickets.Location = new Point(x,y);
            panel1.Controls.Add(chkpremiumtickets);
            x = x - 55;
            if (x < 55)
            {
                y = y+20;
                x = 550;
            }
        }

        x = 550; y = 10;

        Controls.Add(panel1);
```

Answer (score 2):

**How can I get which checkboxes are selected?** 
you can use the [Checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of `CheckBox`(s) for this purpose.

```
  private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if(checkBox1.Checked == true)
          // do something
      else if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
             // do something else.
 }
```

For dynamic controls, you can use:-

```
  foreach(Control ctrl in panel1.Controls)
  {
       if(ctrl is CheckBox)
       {
           CheckBox tempCheckBox = ctrl as CheckBox ; 
           if(tempCheckBox.Checked == true)
               // do something.
       }
  }
```

You can also use the [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property if you want to differentiate b/w different `CheckBox`(s).
 **Using LINQ**

```
  Func<Control, bool> checkedPredicate = (c) => {
                                       if((c is CheckBox)&&(c.Checked == true))
                                          return true ;  
                                       return false ; 
                                   } ; 
 var checkedList =  panel1.Controls.Where(x => checkedPredicate(x)).ToArray() ;
 // this is a array  of checkboxes.
```

Comment: his controls are dynamic, so that wont help!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Control control in panel1.Controls)
{
  if (control is CheckBox)
  {
    if ((control as CheckBox).Checked)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

or simply using LINQ you can get all checked `CheckBox`es within panel:

```
var checkedItems = panel1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(c => c.Checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each control in the Panel and check for a particular type of control and the checked its Tag property for objects you associated it with !

Example below works fine :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int x = 550, y = 10;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var panel1 = new Panel()
            {
                Size = new Size(600, 600),
                Location = new Point(20, 130),
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                Name = "tktPanel",
            };
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                CheckBox chkpremiumtickets = new CheckBox();
                chkpremiumtickets.Text = " ";
                chkpremiumtickets.Name = "chk-" + i.ToString();
                chkpremiumtickets.Location = new Point(x, y);
                panel1.Controls.Add(chkpremiumtickets);
                chkpremiumtickets.Visible = true;
                x = x - 55;
                if (x < 55)
                {
                    y = y + 20;
                    x = 550;
                }
            }

            x = 550;
            y = 10;

            Controls.Add(panel1);
            panel1.Visible = true;

        }

        private IEnumerable<string> GetSelectedBtn()
        {
            //get selected chk_box
            var panel = (Panel)this.Controls["tktPanel"];

            foreach (var control in panel.Controls)
            {
                var chk = control as CheckBox;
                if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
                {
                    yield return chk.Name;
                }
            }
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var chkName in GetSelectedBtn())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(chkName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a collection to keep a reference to the checkboxes and then use the collection to manipulate the checkboxes e.g.

Add a collection member to the Form

```
private List<CheckBox> dynamicCheckboxes = null;
```

Add the checkboxes to the collection at the same time as adding them to the Panel

```
panel1.Controls.Add(chkpremiumtickets);
this.dynamicCheckboxes.Add(chkpremiumtickets);
```

Then, when you want to check which Checkboxes are checked

```
var checkedPremiumTickets = this.dynamicCheckboxes.Where(c => c.Checked);
```

This also decouples the checkbox-state check from the Form container they happen to belong to. Though you may not care about this.